# How to add ListView with datatemplate to Button Flyout in windows store app 8.1 c#

Tags: c#, windows

I have a requirement like when I click on Button Flyout should come with the list of dynamic data and specified template. Below is the code in Xaml. But the Flyout is not Loading with any data.

```
     <Button Content="Folders" >
      <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
          <Flyout >
                <ListView x:Name="lstEmailFolder"  >
                     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                          <Grid>
                              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                               <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                               <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                               </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image Source="/Images/Favorite_icon.png"  Height="30" Width="30" Grid.Column="1" />
                         <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource Foldername}" Width="30" Height="30" Foreground="White" FontSize="20"/>
                          </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
           </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>
     </Flyout>
   </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You havent bind **Itemsource property** to Listview  and instead of **Text="{StaticResource Foldername}"** use Text="{Binding Foldername}"

**xaml**

```
 <Button Content="Display Flyout">
    <Button.Flyout>
        <Flyout>
            <ListView x:Name="lstEmailFolder"  >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>                                
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Foldername}" Width="30" Height="30" Foreground="White" FontSize="20"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </Flyout>
    </Button.Flyout>
</Button>
```

**c#**

```
this.InitializeComponent();
List<FlyoutData> data = new List<FlyoutData>();
data.Add(new FlyoutData("Folder1"));
data.Add(new FlyoutData("Folder2"));
lstEmailFolder.ItemsSource = data;
```

---

```
 public class FlyoutData
{
    public string Foldername { get; set; }

    public FlyoutData(string Foldername)
    {
        this.Foldername = Foldername;

    }
}
```